# expression (RDLC) is not working in Asp.net Core MVC [8.0] Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rdlc

as i know that microsoft doesn't  allow us to use RDLC Reports in web applications in asp.net mvc core...
somehow i managed to mirgate reports from .net framework desktop project to core web application and it works fine.

But when i try to add (expressions at he footer of report: it gives me error on runtime):

> AspNetCore.Reporting.LocalProcessingException: 'An error occurred
> during local report processing.;The definition of the report
> 'wwwroot/Reports/ChartRPT.rdlc' is invalid. An unexpected error
> occurred in Report Processing. Compiler executable file
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v8.0.0\vbc.exe cannot be found.'

i tried to show page x of y: expetced it will work, but it gives an error

Comment: It's not that Microsoft "doesn't allow it" - it's more that you need to be _very careful_ and understand how the reporting system interacts with USER32/GDI/hWnds in a headless environment.

Comment: ...where on earth is it getting the path `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v8.0.0\vbc.exe` from? The `Framework64` directory (as of 2023) won't have any subdirs named higher than `4.0.30319` - not `8.0`

Comment: i'm confused with it too, 
there is no vbc.exe exists in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v8.0.0
maybe the package using AspNetCore.Reporting; is targetting .net 4 or something else?

Comment: Are you able to attach a debugger to the process before it goes haywire and set breakpoints on the places within the BCl where things go wrong?

Comment: @Dai i just copied vbc.exe from 4.0 to 8.0.0 and it is working fine now, i'm genuanily happy that you are there to share happines <3 #Blessings

Comment: ...that shouldn't work _at all_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just copied vbc.exe from 4.0 to 8.0.0 and it is working fine now